# Relationship between $U_{-\phi}A^nU_\phi$ and $(U_{-\phi}AU_\phi)^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have two matrices:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
3 &-1 \\ 
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

$U_\phi=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\phi &-\sin\phi \\ 
\sin\phi & \cos\phi
\end{pmatrix}$

What is the relationship between $U_{-\phi}A^nU_\phi$ and $(U_{-\phi}AU_\phi)^n$? Is there even any?

Comment: Have you tried to calculate $U_{\phi}U_{-\phi}$?

Comment: Yes and I get the Identity matrix. But I wasn't really sure how to use that. Also, as far as I understand I can't just rearrange the order in which I multiply the matrices so I have to multiply with A between $(U_{-\phi})$ and $U_\phi$. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You're missing this: $$(U_{-\phi}AU_{\phi})^n =U_{-\phi}AU_{\phi}U_{-\phi}AU_{\phi}\cdots U_{-\phi}AU_{\phi}$$ Notice all those $U_{\phi}U_{-\phi}$ in there?

Comment: Ahhhh. Of course. I somehow thought that $U_{-\phi}AU_\phi=(U_{-\phi})^nA^nU_\phi^n$. That is not correct, right?

Comment: @Rzeta no. there is no $U_\phi^{\color{red} n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let A, B, and C be matrices such that A is similar to C, this means that: $A = BCB^{-1}$. Now, $A^n = BC^nB^{-1}$. By induction over $n$, the case $n = 1$ is trivial by hypothesis. Now, suppose this was true for $n$, let's verify $n+1$ is true as well:

$$A^{n+1} = (BCB^{-1})^{n+1}$$

Which decomposes into

$$A^{n+1} = (BCB^{-1})(BCB^{-1})^n$$

But, by inductive hypothesis

$$A^{n+1} = (BCB^{-1})(BC^nB^{-1})$$

Now, we can just associate in a convenient way

$$A^{n+1} = BC(B^{-1}B)C^nB^{-1}$$

And then apply definitions

$$A^{n+1} = BCC^nB^{-1}$$

Giving us the identity we wanted:

$$A^{n+1} = BC^{n+1}B^{-1}$$

In particular, notice that your matrix $U$ is singular, which means this relation holds.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks for verifying it too.

Comment: No problem!. Uhm, If this answers your question, you should mark it correct on the left side of the post